# Как сдвинуть скроллбар влево?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

Можно ли задать padding: 5px 5px 5px 0 скроллбару средствами чистого CSS ?
Он находится в полях: Система налогообложения, Количество операций в месяц.

Codepen - https://codepen.io/kwaido/pen/MWBGpEd

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleLi.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=PT+Sans+Caption:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="layer__one">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <p>Тариф</p>
                <button class="dropdown__button"></button>
                <ul class="dropdown__list">
                    <li class="dropdown__list-item" data-value="1">Комплексный</li>
                    <li class="dropdown__list-item" data-value="2">Отчетность</li>
                </ul>
                <input type="text" name="select-category" value="" class="dropdown__input-hidden">
            </div>

            <div class="dropdown">
                <p>Система налогообложения</p>
                <button class="dropdown__button"></button>
                <ul class="dropdown__list">
                    <li class="dropdown__list-item" data-value="2">ОСН</li>
                    <li class="dropdown__list-item" data-value="3">ЕСХН</li>
                    <li class="dropdown__list-item" data-value="4">ПАТЕНТ</li>
                    <li class="dropdown__list-item" data-value="5">ЕНВД</li>
                    <li class="dropdown__list-item" data-value="6">УСН</li>
                    <li class="dropdown__list-item" data-value="7">УСН Д-Р</li>
                </ul>
                <input type="text" name="select-category" value="" class="dropdown__input-hidden">
            </div>

            <div class="dropdown">
                <p>Количество операций в месяц</p>
                <button class="dropdown__button"></button>
                <ul class="dropdown__list">
                    <li class="dropdown__list-item" data-value="1">0-10</li>
                    <li class="dropdown__list-item" data-value="2">10-20</li>
                    <li class="dropdown__list-item" data-value="3">20-30</li>
                    <li class="dropdown__list-item" data-value="4">30-40</li>
                    <li class="dropdown__list-item" data-value="1">40-50</li>
                    <li class="dropdown__list-item" data-value="2">50-60</li>
                    <li class="dropdown__list-item" data-value="3">60-70</li>
                    <li class="dropdown__list-item" data-value="4">70-80</li>
                    <li class="dropdown__list-item" data-value="1">80-90</li>
                    <li class="dropdown__list-item" data-value="2">90-100</li>
                    <li class="dropdown__list-item" data-value="3">100+</li>
                </ul>
                <input type="text" name="select-category" value="" class="dropdown__input-hidden">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="layer__two">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <p>Тип организации</p>
                <button class="dropdown__button"></button>
                <ul class="dropdown__list">
                    <li class="dropdown__list-item" data-value="1">ООО</li>
                    <li class="dropdown__list-item" data-value="2">ИП</li>
                </ul>
                <input type="text" name="select-category" value="" class="dropdown__input-hidden">
            </div>

            <div class="username l1">
                <p>Ваше имя</p>
                <input type="text">
            </div>

            <div class="number ">
                <p>Номер телефона</p>
                <input type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="wrap__calc__button">
        <button class="calc__button">узнать стоимость обслуживания</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    

    <script src="main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown__button {
    
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;

    width: 360px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 15px 24px 15px 12px;
    
    border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    
    transition: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;

    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'PT Sans Caption', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font: #1E1E1E;
    
}

.dropdown__button::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 15px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);


    border-width: 10.4px 6px 0px 6px;
    border-color: #000 transparent transparent transparent;
    border-style: solid;

    pointer-events: none;
    
}

.dropdown__list {
    display: none;
    width: 360px;
    background-color: #fff;

    position: relative; /* ПОМЕНЯТЬ НА RELATIVE, ЧТОБЫ СЪЕЗЖАЛО ВНИЗ */
    left: 0;
    top: 10px;
    
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;

    z-index: 1;

    max-height: 100px;
    overflow-y: overlay;

}

.dropdown__list::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
    height: 55px;
    
    
    
}

.dropdown__list::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    
}

.dropdown__list::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    height: 55px;
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
    border: 3px solid transparent; /* Почему не работает прозрачный? */
    border-radius: 50px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.dropdown__list--visible {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.dropdown__list-item {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding: 15px 13px;

    border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
    border-bottom: 0;
    
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'PT Sans Caption', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font: #1E1E1E;

    cursor: pointer;
    
}

.dropdown__list-item:last-child {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
}

.dropdown__list-item:hover {
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
}

.dropdown__input-hidden {
    display: none;
}

/* Тело */

p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;

    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'PT Sans Caption', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #1E1E1E;
}

input{
    width: 360px;
    height: 50px;

    padding: 16px 14px 16px 14px;

    border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;

    transition: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;

    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'PT Sans Caption', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font: #1E1E1E;
}

.layer__one p {
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.layer__two p {
    padding-top: 40px;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1160px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /* background: whitesmoke; */
    text-align: left;
}

.layer__one {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.layer__two {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.calc__button {

    width: 360px;
    height: 50px;

    margin-top: 60px;

    border-radius: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #DE1010;
    background: #DE1010;

    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'PT Sans Caption', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff;

    cursor: pointer;
}

.wrap__calc__button {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```
document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown').forEach(function (dropDownWrapper) {

    const dropDownBtn = dropDownWrapper.querySelector('.dropdown__button');
    const dropDownList = dropDownWrapper.querySelector('.dropdown__list');
    const dropDownListItems = dropDownList.querySelectorAll('.dropdown__list-item');
    const dropDownInput = dropDownWrapper.querySelector('.dropdown__input-hidden');

    // Клик по кнопке. Открыть/Закрыть селект.
    dropDownBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
        dropDownList.classList.toggle('dropdown__list--visible');
    });

    // Выбор элемента списка. Запомнить выбранное значение. Закрыть дропдаун.
    dropDownListItems.forEach(function (listItem) {
        listItem.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            dropDownBtn.innerText = this.innerText;
            dropDownInput.value = this.dataset.value;
            dropDownList.classList.remove('dropdown__list--visible');
        })
    });

    // Клик снаружи дропдауна. Закрыть дропдаун.
    document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        if ( e.target !== dropDownBtn) {
            dropDownList.classList.remove('dropdown__list--visible');
        }
    })

    // Нажатие на Tab или Escape. Закрыть дропдаун.
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
        if ( e.key === 'Tab' || e.key === 'Escape') {
            dropDownList.classList.remove('dropdown__list--visible');
        }
    })

});
```

Comment: Обернуть еще в один див в котором будет overflow: auto и padding?

Comment: Не совсем понял, что именно нужно обернуть?

Comment: @Даня Подскажи пожалуйста.